# Category Icon Image not being shown in Magento 2, Porto theme

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

I am new on magento2, working to develop multiple stores. Just got stuck with following problem since last many hours. Any positive response is much appreciated

I have created 2 websites, each with one store, and each store with one store view.
[image]

Now, in the PortoStoreView, I am trying to modify the nav menu, by adding category icon. So, from the admin panel, under Category section, I have created new category and set its icon. But it is not displaying the image

[image]

So, I inspect it and found that, it is due to invalid URL of the image. By default image is being stored in following folder:
**store\pub\media\catalog\category**

But it is accessing following path(as can be seen in inspect) to display image.
[image]

At other places for example product page it is working fine, it is displaying the images. But just on the navbar, it is functioning strange.

**Additional Info:**
In my root folder, I have created a folder **PortoStore** and added index.html and .htaccess files in it.
If you need any other information, please ask.

Comment: I think url is not perfect sir. In your url it shows 2 slashes

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below process for multi-store with different URL

1. Install the Magento and configure the server normally for the main site https://www.myprimarydomain.com
2. Now, create a new website, store and store view under Admin > Stores > Settings > All Stores
3. Go To Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web
4. This is the most important step as not selecting the secondary store, you can loose access to the admin panel of the site.

Select secondary store from the store configuration at the top:

5. Configure the Base Url and the secure Base Url according to https://www.mysecondarydomain.com and save the config.
6. Now create a sub-directory(any name, let's say it secondary) at the root of the magento2 installation.
7. Copy the index.php and the .htaccess files from the root of the Magento2 to the subfolder.
8. Replace the code in index.php:

```
<?php
  $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

  /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

  $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);

  $bootstrap->run($app);
?>
```

With

```
<?php

$params = $_SERVER;

    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'secondary'; 
    //Webite code as same in admin panel which we entered in step 2

    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

   /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

    $bootstrap->run($app);
?>
```

And Code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

With

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it and let you know if it works. I really appreciate that.